# Linear search vs binary search efficiency

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, search, binary-search

I am currently studying different search algorithms, and I have made a little program to see the difference in the efficiency. Binary search should be faster than linear search, but the time mesures show otherwise. Did I made some mistake in the code or is this some special case?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

const int n=1001;
int a[n];

void assign() {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i]=i;
    }
}

void print() {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}

bool find1 (int x) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (x==a[i]){
            return true;
        } 
    } return false;
}

bool binsearch(int x) {
    int l=0,m; 
    int r=n-1;
    while (l<=r) {
        m = ((l+r)/2);
        if (a[m]==x) return true;
        if (a[m]<x) l=m+1;
        if (a[m]>x) r=m-1;

    }
    return false;
}

int main() {

    assign();
    //print();
    auto start1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << binsearch(500) << endl;
    auto end1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto start2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << find1(500) << endl;
    auto end2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "binsearch: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end1 - start1).count()
        << " ns " << endl;
    cout << "linsearch: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end2 - start2).count()
        << " ns " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR. On a small enough subset binary search could be slower than linear search due to memory locality.

Comment: Try n=10 millions..

Comment: Did you remember to compile your code with optimizations enabled?

Comment: You forgot the lead-in sentence to all those complexity claims: "There is an `n_0` so that for all `n > n_0` ...".

Comment: Increase your n to higher number step by step, and search for worst case. If n=10000001 and if you find n-2 then I ran your code ` binsearch: 535600 ns
linsearch: 21035900 ns` is the result. if you find 1 then ` binsearch: 532900 ns
linsearch: 238000 ns ` is the result.

Comment: In general, you should be testing against large amounts of data when comparing any algorithm (sorting, searching, whatever).  A thousand items is basically nothing.  Test against millions if not billions (if your memory is large enough) items.

Comment: Note that the `if (a[m]>x)` is unnecessary. You already know that it's not equal and not less. So it must be greater. Change that line to `else r=m-1;`

Answer (score 8):

Your test dataset is too small (1001 integers). It will fit entirely in the fastest (L1) cache when you fill it; consequently, you're bound by branch complexity, not memory. 
The binary search version exhibits more branch mispredictions, resulting in more pipeline stalls than a simple linear pass.

I increased `n` to `1000001` and also increased the number of test passes:

```
auto start1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += n/13) {
    if (!binsearch(i%n)) {
        std::cerr << i << std::endl;
    }
}
auto end1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();

auto start2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += n / 13) {
    if (!find1(i%n)) {
        std::cerr << i << std::endl;
    }
}
auto end2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

and I'm getting different results:

```
binsearch: 10300 ns
linsearch: 3129600 ns
```

---

Note also that you should not call `cout` in a timed loop, but you do need to use the result of the find in order for it to not get optimized away.

Answer (score 7):

To my mind N=1001 is enough to notice that binary search has a better performance. [Specific realizations of linear search](https://dirtyhandscoding.wordpress.com/2017/08/25/performance-comparison-linear-search-vs-binary-search/) could be faster only for small N (approximately < 100). However, in your case the reason of such strange results is incorrect profiling measurements. All your data has been successfully cached during calculations of the first algorithm (binary search), which dramatically improved performance of the second (linear search).

If you just swap their calls, you will get an opposite result:

```
binsearch: 6019 ns 
linsearch: 77587 ns
```

For precise measurements you should use special frameworks ([google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark), for example), which ensures the 'fair conditions' for both algorithms.

Other online [benchmarking tool](http://quick-bench.com/yIz63k1fUX1srE-XwyrlBIWjiXU) (it runs the testing code on a pool of many AWS machines whose load is unknown and returns average result) gives these charts for your code without changes (with the same n=1001 as well):

[image]

Comment: Reusing the cached data makes sense. I haven't thought about that. There is still one thing I don't understand. I have choosen n=1001 and I search for 500 for one reason. In binsearch function m will equal 500 which should lead to only two comparisons - one for the while loop and the first if will return true, whereas in linsearch, the 'for loop' will take 1000 comparisons (i<n and x==a[i]). How come that takes less time?

Comment: But if binsearch is launched first it will have to read uncached data at line ‘a[m]==x’, it costs much more than several comparisons. Anyway, this is a hardware/compiler dependent problem, not a precise profiling. On average, among numerous of function calls, your insight seems to be totally correct, just look at the chart: binsearch returns an answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Get the best of both!

Do a binary search down to some level, then switch to linear.  Think of it this way, a binary search has a bunch of bookkeeping; a linear search is faster because it is 'simpler'.

When I first experimented with this (back in the 1970's) in assembly language, I deduced that doing binary searches down to about 4 items, then doing linear, was about optimal.  However YMMV; It depends on the hardware, the complexity of comparing two items (float / int / string / whatever), etc.

Tip:  Count the number of operations in your code.  I see about twice as many operations are needed for each step in your binsearch() routine versus the linear scan.